# A2dp_sink error when trying to pair HiFi headphones

Tags: sound, headphones

When trying to pair my HiFi headphones to Ubuntu I get the error

```
failed profile to a2dp_sink
```

I am very new to Linux. I have been using Ubuntu for 5 months. The headphones work well on Windows.

Comment: Did you mean HiFi or WiFi?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.